# Take a photo or provide opportunity to choose picture from phone in XNA-game

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, xna

In my XNA-Game I want to provide the oppertunity to take a picutre with the camera of the phone or choose a picture of the memory (**PhotoChooserTask**).

I read something about the **Microsoft.Phone.Tasks**-Namespace. But I can't use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use Microsoft.Phone.Tasks namespace and the tasks inside it also in XNA application, but Microsoft.Phone assembly is not referenced by default in XNA applications so you need to explicitly add it. (Add by right clicking References in Solution Explorer and Microsoft.Phone should be one of the first ones in .NET tab.)